# Mongoose Schema - How to add an order attribute for sorting

Tags: express, sorting, mongoose, schema

I am currently building a web application where you can create setlists (arrays) with an array of lyric objectId's inside, that you can then sort / order into how you want it. So if you would like the 3rd list item to become the first, then you simply drag and drop it to the first line.

I now have a problem in my mongoose schema. I am looking for a way to implement an order attribute or something that would allow me to add a order value such as 0 or 1 depending on the position of the lyrics. Does any of you know how to best implement such order?

Here is a copy of my schema. Currently lyrics is an array of lyric objectId's. But in there i would need an "Order" as well, so that i can sort the array according to the order value.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const SetlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    setlistName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastEdited: { type: Date },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    lyrics: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Lyric'
    }],
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Setlist", SetlistSchema);
```

**Here is the Lyrics schema.**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const LyricSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lyricName: { type: String, required: true },
    lyricContent: { type: String, required: true },
    lastEdited: { type: Date },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Lyric", LyricSchema);
```

If adding an order number isn't the best practice, what can you then recommend as a way of keeping track of which order the user would like the lyrics to show up?

Comment: Can you add Lyric schema to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah - I have now added it. But what has the lyrics schema to do with the setlist schema? I have made it so that you can add lyrics separately from setlists. So lyrics needs to be added as an array into setlists, but with the order / sorting number.

Comment: @SuleymanSah - In the beginning i was thinking about adding the sorting/order number to lyrics, but then i realised that the song can be added into multiple setlists, and it is not sure that it has the same index number in all of them. So i think the order/sorting number has to be saved in the setlist schema.

Comment: Do you have a chance to update Lyric schema to keep the list id?

Comment: @SuleymanSah - Yes i can update that, but i am not sure what it would help. If you mean so that i save the setlist objectId inside the lyric schema that would be a little bit the same as i am doing now, just opposite. Cause right now i am saving the objectId's of the lyrics inside the setlist.

Comment: Ok there is no need in lyric schema. I am trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation framework to sort lyrics by order field. You first need to add a sort field with Number type.

```js
Setlist.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$lyrics"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "lyrics",  // MUST be the PHYSICAL collection name
      localField: "lyrics",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "lyrics"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "lyrics.order": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "lyrics": {
        "$push": "$lyrics"
      },
      "allFields": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$allFields",
          {
            "lyrics": "$lyrics"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D20f_3GS73O)

Sample documents:

```
db={
  "lists": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
      "setlistName": "list1",
      "lastEdited": ISODate("2020-03-18T23:11:56.443+03:00"),
      "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-15T23:11:56.443+03:00"),
      "lyrics": [
        ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000000"),
        ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000001"),
        ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000002")
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
      "setlistName": "list2",
      "lastEdited": ISODate("2020-03-11T23:11:56.443+03:00"),
      "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-11T23:11:56.443+03:00"),
      "lyrics": [
        ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000003"),
        ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000004")
      ]
    }
  ],
  "lyrics": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000000"),
      "name": "Lyric 1",
      "order": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000001"),
      "name": "Lyric 2",
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000002"),
      "name": "Lyric 3",
      "order": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000003"),
      "name": "Lyric 4",
      "order": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000004"),
      "name": "Lyric 5",
      "order": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Output: (as you see lyrics are sorted by order field value)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-15T20:11:56.443Z"),
    "lastEdited": ISODate("2020-03-18T20:11:56.443Z"),
    "lyrics": [
      [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000001"),
          "name": "Lyric 2",
          "order": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000002"),
          "name": "Lyric 3",
          "order": 2
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000000"),
          "name": "Lyric 1",
          "order": 3
        }
      ]
    ],
    "setlistName": "list1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-11T20:11:56.443Z"),
    "lastEdited": ISODate("2020-03-11T20:11:56.443Z"),
    "lyrics": [
      [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000004"),
          "name": "Lyric 5",
          "order": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("6a934e000102030405000003"),
          "name": "Lyric 4",
          "order": 2
        }
      ]
    ],
    "setlistName": "list2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't think this one would work (Or maybe i don't understand it totally). If i understand your answer correctly, then each lyric item will have the same index / order number no matter which setlists it is placed in. So if Lyric 1 with order number 1 is placed inside Setlist 1, it will have Order number 1. And if it is placed inside Setlist 2 it will also have order number 1.  But maybe the lyric "Song number 1" needs to be placed first in the first setlist and then in the second setlist it maybe needs to be placed as number 5.

Comment: @MichaelØrregaardAndersen it is your application's duty how to update correctly. If you keep the order values consistent, this will work.